# Select2 Bootstrap theme How to fix incorrect stylind display?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, jquery-select2

I'm using Select2 with Bootstrap theme (https://github.com/ttskch/select2-bootstrap4-theme).
This is my select:

```
<select style="width: 100%;" id="languages_select" class="form-control js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple" onchange="get_languages()">
    {% for id, name in languages.items %}
        <option value="{{ id }}">{{ name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

And I'm having some errors displaying this field. Looks like this problem is about compability, but I'm using **Bootstrap 4.1** which is supported.
Example:
[image]
This white border gap seems to be caused by placeholder text span, which I can't change in my html because it's rendered by Select2 after everything.
[image]
This one is strange to. This delete button look like not styled.

I know that order of links to jQuery, CSS or JS can cause a problem, so this is my import order:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ttskch/select2-bootstrap4-theme@x.x.x/dist/select2-bootstrap4.min.css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

UPD: Select after changing the order
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly like you said the order of importing css is important. so that you need to reorder your css links order to this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">    
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ttskch/select2-bootstrap4-theme@x.x.x/dist/select2-bootstrap4.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Make sure also to set the theme to bootstrap4 when you initialize the selects with select2. like this:

```js
    $('select').select2({
        theme: 'bootstrap4',
    });
```

this is mentioned in the readme file of https://github.com/ttskch/select2-bootstrap4-theme

Here is a working example:

```js
$('select').select2({
        theme: 'bootstrap4',
    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ttskch/select2-bootstrap4-theme@x.x.x/dist/select2-bootstrap4.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class="form-control">
  <option value="1">option1</option>
  <option value="2">option2</option>
  <option value="3">option3</option>
  <option value="4">option4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This order made it worse :( My Select2 field just got higher when it's empty. When it's filled with choosed field nothing changed.

Comment: I believe that you import the bootstrap css lately. it should be the first import look at my example. second you might be applying another css rules on the select.

Comment: I copypasted your imports. Maybe the main problem is that I use django? I load bootstrap in my base.html and then load css and js in extra block in the head of base.html

Comment: Are you applying any special CSS rules over `id="languages_select"` or `class="js-example-basic-multiple"`?

Comment: Only ```style="width: 100%;"``` and

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2({
    placeholder: 'Выберите языки',
    theme: 'bootstrap4',
  });
});
```

Yes, I can just delete placeholder, but thats not a proper sollution. And It's just 10% of problem